# How to update Datagridview from DataTable?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I use this piece of code:

```
DataTable rows = new DataTable();
rows.Select("name like '%" + name + "%'");
```

So, I need to update DatagridView on result from `rows.Select("name like '%" + name + "%'");`?

I tried this:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = rows.Select("name like '%" + name + "%'");
```

Comment: Is that literally your code or does your DataTable actually have data in it?

Comment: Maybe use this: dataGridView1.DataSource = dataRowArray;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a `DataTable` with data then you can create a `DataView` with filtered data and use that as your `DataSource` like

```
DataView view = rows.DefaultView;
view.RowFilter = "name like '%" + name + "%'";
//Bind it to your GridView
dataGridView1.DataSource = view;
```

Comment: Whats is `dataView`?

Comment: @OlegP, here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I dont see `dataView` in your sample.

Comment: @OlegP, ahh! that's typo ... fixed now. check again

Comment: What is `row.DefaultView;`? Where did you get it?

Comment: @OlegP, `row` is the datatable per your posted code

Comment: @OlegP, those typo issues you can fix yourself I believe ... main point of the answer to convey the way to get this done which the answer does convey ... right?

Comment: Please, fix it, because it is confused me

Comment: Thank you, one moment, why after filter `view.RowFilter` does not work repeated query? Or I need to reset state after first query?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
rows.DefaultView.RowFilter = "name like '" + name  + "%'";
```

And check whatever there is space to be removed by triming the text

Comment: Can you expand your sample, it looks not enough